# Activity A-> B->C->A,but when back from B->A, activity A sets as I left

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three `activities`, A,B and C.
And flow is--- A->B->C->A.

I have already done this using t and I get result perfectly.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(A.this,B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,RC_STATE_LIST);
```

But, I am stuck at the moment where I was in the following situation:

1. A `activity` contains `EditText`, so when i go to `activity` From A to B..And `Activity` A has contains in its edit Text...
   and if i back from the Activity B to  A..I want `activity` A as it is I left it before without using Intent.
2. even I didn't use `OnBackPress` or finish on `Activity` B.

because I have an condition that 
`Activity` B and C both have a back button.

here, if i go A-> b-> C,

and then back from B to C and then I want to back from B to A, still want my Activity 
A as it is.

I referred lots of link provided on StackOverflow, but none worked for me.

What should I do to complete this task? Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you are going from Activity_A to Activity_B don't finish your Activity_A, and from Activity_B, just call onBackPressed();

Comment: i didnt finish Activity A..

Comment: Can you show me the code, how are you going from Activity_A to Activity_B, and how are you coming back.

Comment: Set Edit Text of Activity A value to preference. whwnever you go to A To B . and When You Come bAck again Activity A , then get values from preferance which is previously set.

Comment: @Shekhar,I used finish,nut i dont get output as i want.

Comment: @JJG, i cant save that value to preference.. Is there any other way to do this without using preference?

Comment: @ruhi if you dont want to use shared preferences, you can pass the data along to other activities in your intents `putExtra()` method.

Comment: saving values to preference is the best way to pass data through out application, other wise as sripadRaj , You Can also pass through intent and get data from bundl onactivity result.

Comment: @JJG _"saving values to preference is the best way to pass data"_ Preferences are not intended for that. Intent are (to pass value forward), and `startActivityForResult` to get the value backward.

Comment: Better to add A's xml to more specific question.

Comment: You have to add code and what have you tried with making different possible codition question which you already did.

Comment: Why minus vote?????

Comment: @NitinPatel, s i mentioned all things in my question..i tried that all..new things i didnt try... i tried back press and finish and intent which i cant use...because it didnt give me result as i want

Comment: @ruhi You have to add ActivityA's.xml and all three codes how you startActivity A->B->C, then member will provide you solution that what is wrong with your code. Otherwise you will get only suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
// Add activity
public static void addActivities(String actName, Activity _activity) {
    if (Config.screenStack == null)
        Config.screenStack = new HashMap<String, Activity>();
    if (_activity != null)
        Config.screenStack.put(actName, _activity);
}

// Remove Activity
public static void removeActivity(String key) {
    if (Config.screenStack != null && Config.screenStack.size() > 0) {
        Activity _activity = Config.screenStack.get(key);
        if (_activity != null) {
            _activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

User add activities before setContentView to add into the stack.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addActivities("DemoActivity", DemoActivity.this)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_feed_post);
}
```

If you want to finish all activity when you exist from app you can [**see this code.**](http://developerandroidguide.blogspot.in/2017/04/how-to-remove-particular-activity-from.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In Edittext add **android:freezesText="true"** paremeter it works like a charm.

For detailed information click on the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText).

Comment: Please add some "detailed information", see [answer], link should only provide a complete explanation, but the answer should at least provide the minimum required to understand it. (A link can die or be inaccessible from some networks)

Comment: Thank you for your guideline .freezesText :-control whether this text view or edittext saves its entire text contents when freezing to an icicle, in addition to dynamic state such as cursor position. By default this is false, not saving the text. Set to true if the text in the text view is not being saved somewhere else in persistent storage (such as in a content provider) so that if the view is later thawed the user will not lose their data.

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest file. add launchMode to standard in Activity Tag.

> android:launchMode="standard"

Answer (score -1):

Activity A:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("EditTextData",mEditText.getData().toString());
startActivityForResult(intent,RC_STATE_LIST); // or startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B (if you want to go back to A):

```
private String aData = "";
....    
Intent intent= new Intent(B.this,A.class);
intent.putExtra("EditTextData",aData);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity A:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       .....
       String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("EditTextData");
       mEditText.setText(data);
}
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

*SAVE THE CREDENTIALS into* `sharedPreferences` or `Bundle` and then retrieve or fetch the data in `onCreate()`

Comment: You "solution" to go back to "A" is not correct, it doesn't go back, it ask to show a specific activity. The idea of going back is to use the stack to get to the previous screen. Here, if you have a "C" that can open "B", you would end up in "A" by going back. Not good.

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` then

Answer (score -1):

Activity A:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("EditTextData",mEditText.getData().toString());
startActivityForResult(intent,RC_STATE_LIST); // or startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B (if you want to go back to A):

In this, just call this -->

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: @ruhi, can you try this.

Comment: What is the point to override the `onBackPressed` to only call the super method ? Without the override, it would have call the same method. Please explain the reason there. And FYI, I think OP would have try this without the comment ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

In Activity A's xml add attribute `android:freezesText="true"` in EditText like below:-

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile_no"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/line_border_color"
                android:digits="0123456789+"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_mobile"
                android:inputType="number|textPhonetic"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="13"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:freezesText="true" />
```

Above code freeze the EditText value.

And If you have list and selected item then

```
//Define
int posSelected = -1;
```

In ListView SelectItemListener store that position:

```
posSelected = position;
```

In onResume() Make listview set selection to that position.

Also, Do not `finish();` **A** activity when your starting B Activity (A->B).

```
Intent intent= new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("EditTextA",mEditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
//finish();     //Don't do this because it's main activity you need that on bottom(parent) of stack of Activity in ActivityManager.
```

For condition A->B->C then Direct you want C--->A, you have to finish() B when you are starting C Activity(B->C). Your code should be like below (B->C):-

```
Intent intent= new Intent(B.this,C.class);
intent.putExtra("DataStringB",mEditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
finish();   //For C-->A back or Comment this line if you want back C->B->A
```

Comment: You mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817077/4391450). If you don't have anything to add to this solution, there is no point to duplicate it.

Comment: @ruhi Have you try this way?

Comment: Still are you facing issue?